# How to deal with evil? Validating user input before System.Shell.execute();

Tags: javascript, security, shellexecute, windows-desktop-gadgets, exploit

I'm using a API from Windows gadgets to launch URLs, but I know the destructive power about things like `eval()` and worst and more dangerous, the System.Shell.execute();

But after some research, I think theres no better way to launch URL on the default browser without execute(). Since URLs come from user input, how to prevent users to execute evil-code? My code is SAFE or it can be exploitable? prevent things like this `cmd.exe /c REG QUERY HKCU etc` launching cmd.exe with administrator privileges.

```
function openURL(url){

    var protocol=new Array();

    //Allowed protocols to execute
    protocol[0]='http://';
    protocol[1]='https://';
    protocol[2]='ftp://';
    protocol[3]='search-ms:query=';

    for(var i=0;i<protocol.length;i++){
        if(url.indexOf(protocol[i])==0){

            System.Shell.execute(url);
            break;
        }
    }
}
window.open(); //doesn't work (only open IE);
```

edit:

allowing this 2 protocols is unsafe `file:///` and `javascript:`
exemples that can be done:

`file:///c:/windows/system32/ping.exe`

`javascript:void( window.open('http://file:///c:/windows/system32/ping.exe','','_blank') );`

Comment: What happens if you try to execute multiple commands via the usual shell acrobatics, eg. (http://foo.com & ping.exe)? Does it reject that?

Comment: @3martini the string `http://foo.com & ping.exe` is recognized as a URL and then open the browser with the address `http://foo.com%20&%20ping.exe` and show a 404

Answer (score 0):

Your use sounds like a potential candidate for [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/). It's a project that attempts to sanitize JavaScript from third parties to make it safe for you to run.